# Reference to lookup table in C# LINQ using PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, postgresql, mono

Good day everyone.

I have several tables in PostgreSql.

Main table

```
CREATE TABLE main_table
(
  main_table_id serial NOT NULL,
  ... some data fields ...
  table_type integer,      <--- Foreign key
  CONSTRAINT main_table_id PRIMARY KEY (duty_plan_id),
  CONSTRAINT main_table_to_table_type FOREIGN KEY (table_type)
      REFERENCES table_type(table_type) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

which reference on some lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_type 
(
  table_type integer NOT NULL,
  value character varying(100)
  CONSTRAINT table_type_id PRIMARY KEY (table_type)
)
```

And C# classes mapped to this tables:

```
[Table(Name="main_table")]
    public class MainTable
    {
        [Column(Name="main_table_id", IsPrimaryKey=true,
         IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        internal int Id { get; set; }

        .......

        [Column(Name = "table_type")]
        internal int TableTypeId { get; set; }

        private EntityRef<TableType> _TableType;

        [Association(IsForeignKey = true, ThisKey = "TableTypeId ", 
         Storage = "_TableType", Name = "main_table_to_table_type")]
        public TableType TableType{ 
            get { return _TableType.Entity; }
            set { _TableType.Entity = value; TableTypeId = value.Id; } 
        }

    }

[Table(Name="table_type")]
public class TableType
{
    [Column(Name="table_type", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "value")]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to get list of all MainTable entities

```
(new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<MainTable>().MainTables;
```

from database I got an error:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

This error appear even I didn't call TableType property. But it go away when I comment assotiation string before TableType.

Where I went wrong?

I'm using .Net 3.5, Mono 2.10 and PostgreSql 9.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was solved in next way. I made `TableTypeId` field `public` and modified TableType added back reference to MainTable:

```
[Table(Name="table_type")]
public class TableType
{
    [Column(Name="table_type", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "value")]
    public String Value { get; set; }

    private EntitySet<MainTable> _MainTable = new EntitySet<MainTable>();
    [Association(OtherKey = "TableTypeId", ThisKey = "Id", 
     Storage = "_MainTable")]
    public ICollection<MainTable> MainTable
    {
        get { return _MainTable; }
        set { _MainTable.Assign(value); }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it correct but it works for me.